# How to convert "dd.mm.yyyy" into "yyyy-mm-dd" with Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, date, pandas

I am reading a CSV file with intraday stock market data into a Pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csf('file.csv')
df.columns = ['Day', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume']
df.head()

    Day         Time    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   23.11.2009  17:15   1104.00 1104.00 1104.00 1104.00 2
1   23.11.2009  17:20   1103.00 1103.00 1103.00 1103.00 11
2   23.11.2009  17:25   1103.75 1103.75 1103.75 1103.75 1
3   23.11.2009  17:30   1103.25 1103.25 1102.50 1102.50 3
4   23.11.2009  17:35   1103.25 1103.50 1103.00 1103.00 13
```

Unfortunately the date format in the column "Day" is in European date format: "dd.mm.yyyy". For example "28.11.2016".

How can I easily convert the "Day" column into something like "yyyy-mm-dd" or "2016-11-28"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) just works on your date strings:

```
In [3]:
pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])

Out[3]:
0   2009-11-23
1   2009-11-23
2   2009-11-23
3   2009-11-23
4   2009-11-23
Name: Day, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This returns a `datetime64` column

Note that if you passed `parse_dates=['Day']` to `read_csv` then it would have converted on reading in your csv:

```
In [6]:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=['Day'], index_col=0)
df

Out[6]:
         Day   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0 2009-11-23  17:15  1104.00  1104.00  1104.00  1104.00       2
1 2009-11-23  17:20  1103.00  1103.00  1103.00  1103.00      11
2 2009-11-23  17:25  1103.75  1103.75  1103.75  1103.75       1
3 2009-11-23  17:30  1103.25  1103.25  1102.50  1102.50       3
4 2009-11-23  17:35  1103.25  1103.50  1103.00  1103.00      13
```

Note that pandas generally returns a copy of the data, some methods have an `inplace` arg but `to_datetime` does not so you need to self-assign to overwrite:

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing fast answer! I didn't know it would be that easy. Would you mind if I ask you one more question? After the dates are converted how do I get the converted dates into the "Day" column?

Comment: pandas returns a copy of the data by default so you need to self-assign `df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])`

Comment: Even though your first answer with "to_datetime" answered my question I also wanted to try your other suggestion and do the conversion immediately while reading the file. Unfortunately I was not able to make your line "df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=['Day'], index_col=0)" work. Only after changing it to: "df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', parse_dates=['Day'])" it worked as expected. Thanks for the learning experience!

Comment: My other line was an example, rather than code you should execute verbatim, glad it worked, it is better performance wise to do the conversion where possible on reading the data rather than as a post processing step